# MATLAB: accessing XML object

Tags: xml, matlab

In MATLAB, I load an XML file `docNode = xmlread('stuff.xml');`. `stuff.xml` is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://somesite.com">
    <channel>
        <title>Blah</title>
        <link>http://www.blah.com</link>
        <description>BLAH.COM </description>
        <item>    
            <link>http://www.blah.com/page</link>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I'm trying to retrieve that string in `<link>` but it is proving to be quite tricky.. I'm reading this blog `http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/11/01/xml-and-matlab-navigating-a-tree/` but I still can't figure it out! Can someone chime in on how to get access to `<link>`? TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
>> docNode = xmlread('stuff.xml');
>> l = docNode.getElementsByTagName('link');
>> char(l.item(0).getFirstChild.getData)
ans =
http://www.blah.com
>> char(l.item(1).getFirstChild.getData)
ans =
http://www.blah.com/page
```

PS you have an error in `stuff.xml` - it should be `</channel>`, not `</<channel>`.

---

Edit: To loop directly through each link, you can use `l.getLength`:

```
for i = 0:(l.getLength - 1) % 0-based indexing, not 1-based like MATLAB arrays
    char(l.item(i).getFirstChild.getData)
end

ans =
http://www.blah.com
ans =
http://www.blah.com/page
```

Comment: Hey Sam, yes it does. Thank you so much! If there are more than one `<item>`, how do you loop through them?

Comment: Discard the question. I figured it out shortly after posting it. I'm wondering why you would get the `link` element first instead of serially access it, though. But all works.